# Mac shortcut in Lyx Beamer to have text associated with new frame

Tags: beamer, lyx, mac

What is the Mac shortcut for Alt-Shift-Right in Lyx using Beamer. I have a new environment (new frame) and I am typing text underneath it that does not appear on the slide. In Windows, Alt-Shift-Right does the trick but doesn't seem to work on Mac.

Comment: Does just pressing "tab" work? It works here on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm that pressing "tab" does, in fact, work.

Comment: Can you confirm that this was, in fact, tested on a Mac? ;)